# writing data into multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write data into individual cell of my pandas dataframe but am not able to do it.

For example, my initialized dataframe looks like this:

```
                                  PF44         PF62        PF12         

                                 aa   ss      aa   ss      aa   ss 
1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD           NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
```

I can access a particular element of my dataframe using the following command:

```
>>>feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD']['PF44']['ss']
```

and the output is `nan`. However, if I want to change this to say a number `5` or a text `'test'`, I used the following commands:

```
>>>feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD']['PF44']['ss'] =5
```

or

```
>>>feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD']['PF44']['ss']='test'
```

neither returned any error but when the check the value:

```
>>>feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD']['PF44']['ss']
```

its still shows

```
nan
```

Comment: What does feat_df.index and feat_df.columns return? What does feat_df.head(5).to_dict() Output. Add this to you question so we can get a clear structure of your dataframe.

Comment: It seems like you are modifying the copy of dataframe and not dataframe itself. Does the IDE show any warnings?

Comment: @HarvIpan no, IDE does not show any warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD', ('PF44','ss')] = 5
```

or

```
feat_df.loc['1B38:A|ABCDE|DDFE|QUAD', ('PF44','ss')] = 'test'
```

Use tuples to access MultiIndex Column headers.